# User input path not recognised by os.path.abspath

Tags: python, path, operating-system

I am writing a script in which I want the user to input a file path that will then be parsed by the rest of the script as a way to know which file to work on.

For brevity here is the beginning of the code which is where I have a problem:

```
### import modules
import pyabf

#### open file and extract basic data 
file_path = input('file path?')
abf = pyabf.ABF(file_path)
data = abf.data
```

If I run the script in this form I get the following error:

File "/Users/XXX/anaconda3/envs/blah_blah/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyabf/abf.py", line 65, in **init**
    raise ValueError("ABF file does not exist: %s" % self.abfFilePath)
ValueError: ABF file does not exist

And here the portion of the script that gives me this error:

```
# clean-up file paths and filenames, then open the file
    self.abfFilePath = os.path.abspath(abfFilePath)
    if not os.path.exists(self.abfFilePath):
        raise ValueError("ABF file does not exist: %s" % self.abfFilePath)
    self.abfID = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.abfFilePath))[0]
    log.debug(self.__repr__())
```

If I run the lines of the code individually in the console everything works:

```
abf = pyabf.ABF(file_path)  # same path as before works to open the file 
data = abf.data # then manages to extract the correct numpy array.
```

What happens to the path when it is fed into as user input as opposed to being given directly into the argument where it will be used? I have tried to type the path in different ways with or without '' or () but I can't get it to be recognised by the pyabf.ABF script.

I had a look at the os.path info and from what I can understand the os.path.abspath(abfFilePath) line, which is bugging now, should just return an absolute path name. I'm sure it's probably something simple and obvious that I just don't get.

Hopefully someone here can help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you verified whether the user has rights to access the file they enter or that the file isn't hidden?

Comment: Sorry can you clarify this? The file is in a normal folder, i.e. not a hidden systems type folder - if this is what you mean. And there are no restrictions on it - anyone can read and write it.  I'm running on mac OS 10.12 and use Python 3.6 in Spyder in case it makes a difference. Forgot to add it to my original post.

Comment: I'm going to guess `abspath` is using the script root instead of the user's working directory.  This explains why it works when you run the code manually in a console vs from a script.

Comment: The message that you report is `ABF file does not exist` but the code that produces this message follows that with a colon and the name of the path that your code does an existence check on. What is the filename that `os.path.exists()` is complaining about? I suspect that when you run it in a script, your current working directory is not what you expect, and so `abspath` is causing `exists` to look in the wrong place.

Comment: Sorry just to make sure I understand your feedback. The problem is that my new script and the pyABF script that I am referencing to are not in the same folder?

Comment: Also this is the exact Value error I get: ValueError: ABF file does not exist: /Users/name.redacted/Documents/work_place/Data/OPSIN_testing_project/Opsin_Ephys_Analysis/'/Users/name.redacted/Documents/work_place/Data/OPSIN_testing_project/Opsin_Ephys_Analysis/2019_02_22_0021.abf' . I can see that the path file name has been doubled, except the final part which is the actual file name.